# How to retrieve contacts from emulator to my application in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a contact list application in my android phone. I want to retrieve all the contact list from emulator and the contacts should be listed.

Answer (score 2):

Even API Demo samples has a similar program

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phones.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(c);            
// Map Cursor columns to views defined in simple_list_item_2.xml
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 
new String[] { Phones.NAME, Phones.NUMBER },
new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I have already attached a snippet source. Populate it in a listview and you should be able to see the contacts there...